# Twill causing print() not to show

Tags: python, pandas, twill

I'm trying to use Twill with Jupyter/Python. However if I use Print() after I've imported Twill eg.

```
from twill.commands import go, showforms, formclear, fv, submit, show

print("hi")
```

it won't print anything.

Is this normal behaviour?

This happens on google colan and jupyterLab

Comment: Just tried it and there was no output from the print('hi')

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your module has its own `sys` module which makes troubles with Jupyter upon import.

Try this:

```
from twill.commands import go, showforms, formclear, fv, submit, show
import sys

sys.stdout = stdout

print ('hi')
```

Otherwise I'd just recommend never using those online notebooks which are, to my opinion, essentially limiting because of unexpected behaviors not easy to solve due to a lack of documentation relative to main Python.